# C variable not getting initialized

Tags: c, ansi-c

When debugging the following code snippet, I observed that `function = copy_string(temp_function);` does not initialize the variable function (still points at 0x0), even though on `return copy` copy from `copy_string()` points to an initialized memory address containing the correct result.

```
static char* copy_string(char* string)
{
    char* copy = NULL;
    uint32_t length = 0U;

    length = strlen(string);
    copy = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length +1));
    strcpy(copy, string);

    return copy;
}

static void separate_test(const char* test_name, char* function, char* scenario, char* expected_result)
{
    const char* delimiter = "__";
    char* new_test_name = NULL;
    char* temp_function = NULL;
    char* temp_scenario = NULL;
    char* temp_expected_result = NULL;
    uint32_t length = strlen(test_name);

    new_test_name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length +1));
    strcpy(new_test_name, test_name);
    temp_function = strtok(new_test_name, delimiter);
    function = copy_string(temp_function);
    temp_scenario = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    scenario = copy_string(temp_scenario);
    temp_expected_result = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    expected_result = copy_string(temp_expected_result);
}
```

The function is called with the following parameters:

```
const char* test_name = "function_name__scenario__expected_result";
char* function = NULL;
char* scenario = NULL;
char* expected_result = NULL;

separate_test(test_name, function, scenario, expected_result);
```

What is the cause of this behavior?

Edit:
Fixed allocation issue.

Comment: What does strlen() do.

Comment: @self What do you mean?

Comment: @IsKernel that you are not reserving enough memory with `malloc(sizeof(char) * length)`

Comment: @self True, didn't allocated enough memory. But this wasn't the problem.

Comment: @ouah I fixed that, but it wasn't the issue. Thanks for noticing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reserve space for the null terminator. This line:

```
copy = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
```

Should be:

```
copy = malloc(length + 1);
```

`sizeof(char)` is always 1, so you don't need it here.

Also, recall that parameters in C are passed by value, so the changes you make to `test_name`, `function`, etc, inside `separate_test()` are not seen by the caller. You might want to pass pointers to pointers instead, like so:

```
const char* test_name = "function_name__scenario__expected_result";
char* function = NULL;
char* scenario = NULL;
char* expected_result = NULL;

separate_test(test_name, &function, &scenario, &expected_result);
```

`separate_test()` becomes:

```
static void separate_test(const char* test_name, char** function, char** scenario, char** expected_result)
{
    const char* delimiter = "__";
    char* new_test_name = NULL;
    char* temp_function = NULL;
    char* temp_scenario = NULL;
    char* temp_expected_result = NULL;
    uint32_t length = strlen(test_name);

    new_test_name = malloc(length+1);
    strcpy(new_test_name, test_name);
    temp_function = strtok(new_test_name, delimiter);
    *function = copy_string(temp_function);
    temp_scenario = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    *scenario = copy_string(temp_scenario);
    temp_expected_result = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    *expected_result = copy_string(temp_expected_result);
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Hah! Good catch. I edited my answer, thanks for noting.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value of `function` and other variables in `separate_test`. However, since they are passed by value, that does change the values of those variables in the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `function` parameter in `seperate_test` is a temporary variable. So it takes a random address to which it points to, since the before calling it the variable is initialized to NULL. Si I would advise to make a : `function = malloc(sizeof(function))` before calling the function or returning the function parameter.